# How do I autopromote MediaWiki user based on a specific set of email addresses?

Tags: mediawiki

I'd like to setup a MediaWiki installation for my school board, and give a 'teacher' user group more privileges than a student user group.

All teachers in the board have @boardname.com email addresses, so identifying them this way is easy.

How do I easily autopromote them to a teacher group?

The manual gives this example..

```
$wgAutopromote[ 'teacher' ] = array (
    '&',
        APCOND_EMAILCONFIRMED,
);
```

or could get the emailconfirmed code to check?

Answer (score 0):

From [Autopromote.php](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-core/blob/master/includes/Autopromote.php) it seems that it's not possible to add new conditions (unless you start hacking MediaWiki core, which you shouldn't unless you plan to send in a patch). And there's no email regexp condition yet.

So your best option is to add a simple extension that first checks `APCOND_EMAILCONFIRMED` (to make sure the user actually owns the email address they signed up with) and then based on the email address will add the user to the `teachers` group.